# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA run all the tests in a package including sub packages

Tags: intellij-idea

If I click on a package and do control-shift-F10 it only looks for and runs JUnit tests in that package - but I really want it to recurse down into subpackages and run them.

UPDATE: looks like its something else wrong. When I run it on a package that has tests, it still complains there are none (yet if I open a JUnit test I can run it just fine).

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F10 goes into sub-dirs for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. On the package level IntelliJ finds only testcases in classes that extend TestCase. Annotated test methods are not found.

Comment: I don't remember closing it off? Certainly not in Nov 08? (just had a baby then, hardly would have been on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default key combination to run all tests is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: sorry I meant I already tried that. It just says there are no tests in that package.

Comment: I think he meant Alt+Shift+F10 -> Create a new junit test configuration -> name it "All tests" -> include entire package -> Apply/Run.

Comment: @andersoyvind this answer is so far from that one that it really would deserve an answer of its own

Comment: This saved my a$$

Answer (score 193):

1. Run->Edit Configurations...
2. Create a new junit test configuration
3. Name it "All tests"
4. Include entire package
5. Apply/Run.

[image]

From @andersoyvind's comment.

Comment: Alt+shift+F10 does nothing for me :/

Comment: Alt+Shift+F10 is the default keyboard shortcut for the "Run->Run..." action.  If you are not using the default keyboard shortcut you can use the menu.  P.S. I've changed the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: I get an error that 'cover is disabled when per-module working directory is configured. Please specify single working directory, or change test scope to single module'. In your screenshot if I give the working directory value as `$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$` then it seems to be working though few unit test cases failed and I am also able to select each module if required

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this thanks to [csauve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65580/csauve) [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443830/968925). This could be an answer to his, but I didn't know how to include an image there.

*Run/Debug Configurations* dialog box can be access via **Run > Edit Configurations**. Use these options to create one that runs all your tests:

[image: Run/Debug configuration for all tests]

Answer (score -3):

For **Python** users:

1. Include `__init__.py` in each subfolder
2. Create a `dummy_test.py` in the root of your tests directory, eg.:

```py
class DummyTest(TestCase): 
    pass
```

([credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072638/3508719))